# Making a Makefile for C++ project

Tags: c++, makefile

Ok I Have a problem making a MakeFile for C++ project in Windows. I checked around and found some tutorials and this is what I got:

```
IDIR =../include
CC = g++
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR = obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

_DEPS = Button.hpp
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = Test.o Button.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

Test.exe: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

And this is the error message that pops up:
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/Test.o', needed by 'Test.exe'.  Stop.

EDIT:

Hi I'm still having trouble with my makefile. The point is that my project folder is a mess and I want to keep it neat.
My make file is having trouble working across multiple directories. Now all my cpp files, header files and object files are clumped in one folder and that works but since I'm adding more to my program it is becoming messy. I managed to make it work to have headers in one directory but objects are problematic hence I'm asking for help again.

This is my Makefile now:

```
IDIR = Headers
ODIR = obj
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -I$(IDIR) $(LIBS)

LIBS = -lm -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

_DEPS = Button.hpp TextBox.hpp TextToWindow.hpp MessageBox.hpp CheckBox.hpp
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = Button.o TextBox.o TextToWindow.o MessageBox.o CheckBox.o Test.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)

Test.exe: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CPPFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    del $(ODIR)*.o *.exe
```

And this is my working dir:

```
MainDir:
     -Headers:
         -hpp
         -hpp
           .
           .
     -cpp
     -o
     -cpp
       .
       .
```

It is working for headers but it cant make objects in that dir hence the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/Button.o', needed by 'Test.exe'.  Stop.
```

Comment: The error says that no rule applies to build `obj/Test.o`. If it was a problem due to the non-existing `obj` directory the error would be different and would come from the recipe (the compilation command). More likely you don't have a source file named `Test.c` or a header file named `../include/Button.hpp`.

Comment: To automatically create the `obj` directory when needed simply add `mkdir -p $(@D)` to your recipe or, slightly better, add a rule to create it and declare it as an [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) of all object files.

Comment: I changed the "$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)"  to:  "$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)" since it needs to look for %.cpp files but it didn't work. it can't find the necessary files to make Test.o so it can continue. I work on windows and in c++ is there something I wrote wrong since this is based on https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ if I write a makefile with simple commands it works it is just pain to write it all down this is much shorter since I want to add more files to my test program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I made it like this and it works, but I still can't make it work in multiple directories.

```
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -I $(LIBS)

LIBS = -lm -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

DEPS = Button.hpp TextToWindow.hpp

OBJ = Test.o Button.o TextToWindow.o

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)

Test.exe: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CPPFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f /*.o *~ core /*~
```

Oh, and the clean function doesn't work. If anyone can suggest a better way please do. Thanks!

Comment: I added $(LIBS) to CPPFLAGS because it if I make changes to some of the code and run make it doesn't add $(LIBS). it used to be $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIBS) in object rule and $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIBS) in main exe creation rule

Comment: `rm -f /*.o *~ core /*~` will try to erase files in the root directory, probably not desired.